# Problems solvable in time $f(n)$ but not in time $o(f(n))$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Suppose I have some (increasing, nice asymptotics) function $f(n)$. Does there exist a complexity theoretic problem (e.g. PATH, 3-SAT, GO etc.) that can be solved in time $\Omega(f(n))$ on a deterministic Turing machine. In other words is there a problem proven to be an element of $\mathsf{DTIME}(f(n))$, but not $\mathsf{DTIME}(g(n))$ for any function $g$ such that $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Check out the [Time Hierarchy Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem).

Comment: The title of your post didn't match the body of your post. I modified it to reflect your post. If you're also interested in the question in the original title, please ask it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the language of all binary words which consist only of zeroes. It can be decided on a deterministic Turing machine in time $O(n)$, but not in time $o(n)$.

For general [time-constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function#Time-constructible_definitions) functions $f(n)$, the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) shows that the problem of deciding whether a Turing machine halts in time $f(n)$ can be solved in time $O(f(n)\log f(n))$ but not in time $o(f(n))$. It is not known how to eliminate this logarithmic gap in general.